# JavaScript: How to create a function that receives an array of numbers and returns an array containing only the positive numbers?

Tags: javascript, challenge-response

What is Wrong with this Code? I should create a function that receives an array of numbers and returns an array containing only the positive numbers. How can it be modified? Especially Modified. Not another code!

```
all = prompt("Give me an array of numbers seperated by ','");

var splitted = all.split`,`.map(x=>+x);
function returner(splitted){
    var positive = [];

for(var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++);{
    var el = splitted[i];
    if (el >= 0){
        positive.push(el);
    }
    
}
return positive;
}

var positive = returner(splitted);
print(positive);
```

Comment: I vote to close this as a typo: you have a semi colon at the end of the `for` line, which means the code block that follows it, is not the body of the `for` loop. That block will have `i` equal to the length of the array...

Comment: Does this code actually run? If it does, what input are you providing, what result are you seeing, and what result were you expecting?

Comment: Also use `console.log` instead of `print`. `print` will launch the printer dialog :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I noticed that you are using `print` to check your output - that should be `console.log()`.
But your real mistake is the semicolon after the for bracket in line 7.

Here is a working code-snippet:

```js
let all = prompt("Give me an array of numbers seperated by ','");

let splitted = all.split`,`.map(x => +x);
function returner(splitted) {
    let positive = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
        const el = splitted[i];
        if (el >= 0) {
            positive.push(el);
        }
    }

    return positive;
}

var positive = returner(splitted);
console.log(positive);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the semicolon after the `for` statement as:

```js
all = prompt("Give me an array of numbers seperated by ','");

var splitted = all.split`,`.map(x=>+x);
function returner(splitted){
    var positive = [];

for(var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++){
    var el = splitted[i];
    if (el >= 0){
        positive.push(el);
    }
    
}
return positive;
}

var positive = returner(splitted);
console.log(positive);
```

practically with that semicolon you were doing "nothing" `n` times and then executing the block on it's own which didn't help filling your array since the `i` variable is already passed the last index of the array and so `splitted[i]` results to `undefined` which is not `>=0` thus nothing gets pushed to the `positive` array.

(also I'd imagine you want a `console.log` at the end instead of `print`? )

Comment: Please vote to close as typo instead of answering.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `filter`?

```js
var array = [3, -1, 0, 7, -71, 9, 10, -19];

const getpositiveNumbers = (array) => array.filter(value => value > 0);

var positives = getpositiveNumbers(array);

console.log(positives);
```

Anyway, as @trincot noticed, your code is wrong.